How to create a Windows Control Panel window using CLSID in Powershell?
I have just recently learned that one can start Control Panel windows in Windows 10 via these windows CLSID; the only list I've found so far is https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/CLSID-List.htm , where I can see:




CLSID
Location
Availability




::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}
Network Connections
XP-11




So, in essence, all you have to do is run this in cmd.exe:
start ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

... and a Control Panel \ Network Connections window will be started:

So, I was wondering, how do you do the same in PowerShell?
The closest I got to it, was using CreateInstance with GetTypeFromCLSID (via this):
PS C:\tmp> $comObject = [Activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromCLSID("{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}"))

PS C:\tmp> $comObject
System.__ComObject

PS C:\tmp> $comObject | Get-Member                                                                         

   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetType                   Method     type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method     string ToString()

So, clearly, the object created from CLSID is there - but I cannot get the window to appear?
So, how can I get the Control Panel \ Network Connection window to be started / to appear, by using its CLSID {7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E} in PowerShell?

EDIT: Re:

You do not need the CLSID, in Windows 10.

That is true in general, but I do need the CLSID, because I want to eventually open a specific network connection from Conrol Panel \ Network Connections, as described in how to open tcp/ip properties from cmd or run directly? - Super User, which works in general but I couldn't get the explorer shell:::{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}\::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-  00805FC1270E}\::%ServiceName% to work in Powershell (if I execute the rest of that script, and compose a final string from the results to paste in cmd, then I got it to work) - so I just wanted to keep things simple for this question.

Well, after some mucking about, I eventually found Powershell equivalent of Batch command "START" to open window with Mapped Drive, where it is noted:


While start is an internal cmd.exe command, PowerShell has an alias named start for its own Start-Process cmdlet; if you pass a drive specification, the two commands work the same.

Alternatively, you could have used the Invoke-Item cmdlet (Invoke-Item X:\)




I could not get Invoke-Item to work - however, I can confirm these commands worked for me - note the CLSID must be specified as a string:
start "::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}"         # ✔️

... and:
Start-Process "::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}" # ✔️

Also, i found Running CMD command in PowerShell, where it is noted:

One solution would be to pipe your command from PowerShell to CMD.

... and can confirm this works (note again, it is a string that should be piped):
"start ::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}" | cmd   # ✔️

... however, I couldn't get piping into start/Start-Process to work:
PS C:\tmp> "::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}" | start

cmdlet Start-Process at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilePath: v
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:46
+ "::{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}" | start
+                                              ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Regardless, I do have some commands (syntaxes) that work - so good enough for me for now ... though I'd love to know if a Powershell expert can suggest some other/better approaches ...

You should try asking at https://github.com/orgs/PowerShell/discussions/new?category=q-a about things like not being able to pipe the CLSID, since that's quite strange behaviour. I'd be as interested as you are in why that's dysfunctional.

Thanks for the suggestion @RokeJulianLockhart - posted on Why does piping of CLSID to start fail? · PowerShell · Discussion #21541

For future readers, the URI has moved to https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/discussions/21541#discussion-6567097.

You do not need the CLSID, in Windows 10.
The following should work fine in both powershell.exe and cmd.exe.
start ms-settings:network

start is an alias for start-process in PowerShell.
There are also these options too:
start ms-settings:network-cellular

start ms-settings:network-dialup

start ms-settings:network-directaccess

start ms-settings:network-ethernet

start ms-settings:network-mobilehotspot

start ms-settings:network-proxy

start ms-settings:network-status

start ms-settings:network-vpn

start ms-settings:network-wifi

start ms-settings:network-wificalling

start ms-settings:network-wifisettings


Thanks @Compo - I actually do need the CLSID, that is why I formulated the question as I did; added an edit to OP to clarify.

Those open the Settings application's XAML pages, not the individual .cpls which control.exe consumes.

I know what they open, thankyou @RokeJulianLockhart. The answer was provided before the OP submitted additional information which made it less useful to them. However, future readers will nonetheless find it useful. Additionally, the solution required was to start-process , or better yet, its alias start, (for cross compatability), as also later submitted by the OP.

@Compo, sorry - my vote's locked in now. Damn SO.

That's fine @RokeJulianLockhart, I'm not chasing points, don't worry about it.

Well, depending on what you're trying to achieve here, maybe Show-ControlPanelItem would work?
PS C:\Windows\system32> Show-Control PanelItem
cmdlet Show-Control PanelItem at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]: Date and Time
Name[1]: Sound
Name[2]:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Show-Control PanelItem


You should copy that log as text, instead of a screenshot. Also, for other readers, the docs are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/show-controlpanelitem?view=powershell-5.1. I've submitted https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/5635616.
